# Prevent data modification through stored proc

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL Server 2005 database, a user belongs to a role and that role has been granted execute permission on all the stored procedures. One of the stored procedures inserts data into the table called `tableA`.

User has been explicit DENY permission on `tableA`. However, user can still execute stored procedure to insert new data.

Is there a way to prevent user to insert new data into the table (besides removing user from the role which has execute permission)

```
create table tableA
(id int identity(1,1), data varchar(20)
)

create proc uspInsertTableA
   (@data varchar(20))
with execute as caller
as
begin
insert into tableA
values (@data)
end

DENY INSERT On tableA TO BrianG

GRANT EXECUTE on uspInsertTableA to BrianG
```

BrianG, can still insert data

```
exec uspInsertTableA 'yada'
```

Comment: If the user has the permission to execute the stored procedure - that's all he needs to execute that procedure - no matter what that procedure does. If he's not supposed to call that procedure - you need to `DENY EXECUTE` **on that procedure** - there's no other way to stop him from calling that proc.

Comment: thanks marc_s for code edit and your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two relevant factors:

1. "execute as" of the stored procedure.
2. Ownership chaining.

"EXECUTE as CALLER" is already the default (CREATE PROCEDURE ... WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER ...)

Additionally the stored procedure must have a different owner than TableA, to prevent ownership chaining. The owner of the stored procedure must not have the right to insert into the table.

Alternatively you could use the HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME function within the stored procedure to explicitly check whether the user has the permission.

```
if HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('TableA','OBJECT','INSERT') = 0
   raiserror ('User is not allowed to insert into TableA',16,1)
```

Comment: Well, what you suggested will not work as execute as caller is the default and called has execute permission.

Comment: sorry, I tested with a script but what you said does not work...not sure how I can post my repro script.

Comment: Did you see my addition that the stored procedure and the table must have different owners?

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the database schema of the sproc? ie. change from dbo.Insert to protected.Insert?

Then you could deny exec against this schema?